# Python: compare 3 columns in 2 csv files and output if they are equal

Tags: python, csv, python-3.5

So I've got two CSV files that I'm trying to compare and get the results of the similar items. The first file, hosts.csv is shown below:

```
Path    Filename    Size    Signature
C:\     a.txt       14kb    012345
D:\     b.txt       99kb    678910
C:\     c.txt       44kb    111213
```

The second file, masterlist.csv is shown below:

```
Filename    Signature
b.txt       678910
x.txt       111213
b.txt       777777
c.txt       999999
```

As you can see the rows do not match up and the masterlist.csv is always larger than the hosts.csv file. The only portion that I'd like to search for is the Signature portion. I know this would look something like:

hosts[3] == masterlist[1]
I am looking for a solution that will give me something like the following (basically the hosts.csv file with a new RESULTS column):

```
Path    Filename    Size    Signature    RESULTS
C:\     a.txt       14kb    012345       NOT FOUND in masterlist
D:\     b.txt       99kb    678910       FOUND in masterlist (row 1)
C:\     c.txt       44kb    111213       FOUND in masterlist (row 2)
```

I've searched the posts and found something similar to this here but I don't quite understand it as I'm still learning python.

Edit Using Python 3.5

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import csv
masterlist = list(csv.reader(open('masterlist.csv')))
host = list(csv.reader(open('host.csv')))
masterlist_dict = {a:b for a, b in zip(["Filename", "Signature"], masterlist)}
final_result = [["Path", "Filename", "Size","Signature", "RESULTS"]] +
               [[path, filename, size, signature, "NOT FOUND"] 
                if signature in masterlist_dict["Signature"] 
                else [path, filename, size, signature, 
                      "FOUND (row {})".format(
                         masterlist_dict["Signature"].index(signature) 
                      for path, filename, size, signature in host]
write = csv.writer(open("new_host.csv", 'a')))
write.writerows(final_results)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `csv.DictReader` and `csv.DictWriter` objects:

```
import csv

with open('hosts.csv', 'r') as hosts, open('masterlist.csv', 'r') as mlist, \
     open('result.csv', 'w', newline='') as res:

    host_reader = csv.DictReader(hosts, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
    mlist_reader = csv.DictReader(mlist, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(res, fieldnames=host_reader.fieldnames + ['Result'], delimiter='\t')

    mlist_data = {r['Signature']: mlist_reader.line_num-1 for r in mlist_reader}
    fmt = '{0}FOUND in masterlist{1}'   # prepearing output format for `Result` field
    writer.writeheader()                # writing header

    for r in host_reader:
        if r['Signature'] in mlist_data:
            r['Result'] = fmt.format(""," (row "+str(mlist_data[r['Signature']])+")")
        else:
            r['Result'] = fmt.format("NOT ","")
        writer.writerow(r)
```

---

`result.csv` contents:

```
Path    Filename    Size    Signature   Result
C:\ a.txt   14kb    012345  NOT FOUND in masterlist
D:\ b.txt   99kb    678910  FOUND in masterlist (row 1)
C:\ c.txt   44kb    111213  FOUND in masterlist (row 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would always prefer a pandas dataframe to do such stuff, because it delivers a wide range of different functions to save and edit `.csv`-files. [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html#csv)

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('1.csv')
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('2.csv')
df['result'] = 0
for i in xrange(df['signature'].__len__()):
    for j in xrange(df2['signature'].__len__()):
        if df['signature'][i] == df2['signature'][j]:
            df.loc[i, ('result')] = 'found in \'2.csv\' at row ' + str(
                df2.signature[df2.signature == df2['signature'][j]].index.tolist())
            break
df.to_csv('out.csv')
```

Where `1.csv` = `hosts.csv` and `2.csv` = `masterlist.csv`, and saves the whole output as `out.csv`. The output looks like:

```
  path filename  signature                          result
0  C:\    a.txt      12345                               0
1  D:\    b.txt     678910     found in '2.csv' at row [0]
2  C:\    c.txt     111213  found in '2.csv' at row [1, 4]
```

and my `.csv`-files look like the following.

**First**: `1.csv`

```
  path filename  signature
0  C:\    a.txt      12345
1  D:\    b.txt     678910
2  C:\    c.txt     111213
```

**Second:** `2.csv`

```
  filename  signature
0    b.txt     678910
1    x.txt     111213
2    b.txt     777777
3    c.txt     999999
4    b.txt     111213
```

so I can see if there are **multiple occurances** of the signature in `2.csv`, and save where to find them.